# Why static linking Python can use dynamic libraries on Linux

Tags: python

On **Windows**, I can't use **pyd** for a static **pythoncore** because the dynamic library can't get python functions address directly.
But I found it can do that on **Linux**. I used `--disable-shared` for configure to compile, the `.so` libraries still work for dynamic import.
What different between them? Can use a static C extension for dynamic import on Windows?

Comment: Can you check the symbols exported by the Python binary by using `objdump -R python`. Windows binary doesn't export symbols but Linux binary does.

Comment: Yes, Linux exports python symbols. On Windows, event you export the entry ( like PyInit_XXX ), but there are separate memory spaces between  `.dll` and `.exe` ( they link to different C Runtime, `/MT` and `/MD`). So the dynamic library can't use python API directly.